# Binding ajax.Success and doc.Ready

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function that needs to run after the page has loaded as well as on ajax events, as much of my site is loaded asynchronously via ajax using  c# /asp.net / mvc4 (which im still new very new to) Ajax.ActionLink and Partial View.

Does anyone know how I can trigger this function on both events? I currently am having to duplicate the function twice, once on ajax.success and then again on doc.ready

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: stick it in a function and pass the function around.

Answer (score 1):

You can stay DRY by creating an object that encapsulates the logic you need to perform, and then call it whenever is appropriate.

```
// don't pollute the global namespace
var MyApplication = {
     theLogic: function() {
         alert('performing logic');
     }
};

 // document ready/page loaded
 $(function() {
    MyApplication.theLogic();
 });

 // after ajax calls
 $.ajax({
    ...
    success: function() { MyApplication.theLogic(); }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the first problem of waiting until the page loads by either using

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    //This will be be run once DOM is initialized
});
```

or using the onload

```
document.body.onload = function () {
    //Fired when DOM is loaded
}
```

From there you can call your AJAX call or function with an AJAX call like so:

```
$(function () { 
    $.ajax({
        url : "",
        success : function () {...}
    });
});
```